# Button with multiple icons

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS button definition that looks like this:

```
.btn {
        display: inline-block;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        padding: 12px 24px;
        border: 1px solid #acacac;
        border-radius: 8px;
        background: #f5f5f5;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#f5f5f5), to(#acacac));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #f5f5f5, #acacac);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5f5f5, #acacac);
        -webkit-box-shadow: #ffffff 0px 0px 40px 0px;
        -moz-box-shadow: #ffffff 0px 0px 40px 0px;
        box-shadow: #ffffff 0px 0px 40px 0px;
        text-shadow: #ffffff 1px 1px 1px;
        font: normal normal bold 20px arial;
        color: #111111;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .btn:hover,
    .btn:focus {
        border: 1px solid #f5f5f5;
        background: #ffffff;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#cecece));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #cecece);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #cecece);
        color: #111111;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    .btn:active {
        background: #acacac;
        background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#acacac), to(#acacac));
        background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #acacac, #acacac);
        background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #acacac, #acacac);
    }
    .btn:before{
        content:  "\0000a0";
        display: inline-block;
        height: 24px;
        width: 24px;
        line-height: 24px;
        margin: 0 4px -6px -4px;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        background: url("../img/rn.png") no-repeat left center transparent;
        background-size: 100% 100%;
    }
```

I need couple of those buttons on my page but with different icons.

I tried something like this:

```
.client{    
    background: url("../img/client.png") no-repeat left center transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.poslovnica{    
    background: url("../img/poslovnica.png") no-repeat left center transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

And calling it with:

```
<p><a class="btn client" href="#">Klijenti</a></p>
<p><a class="btn poslovnica" href="#">Poslovnice</a></p>
```

But that did not work.

I'm still struggling with HTML and CSS so I'd like to stay away from java, jQuery and such till I'm a bit more comfortable with HTML/CSS.

Here's a working test in jsFiddle: [jsfiddle.net/8hKGf/3](http://jsfiddle.net/8hKGf/3)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: Can you put in a Fiddle?

Comment: yes. here it is http://jsfiddle.net/8hKGf/3/

Comment: Out of UX  perspective, I would URGE you to change the buttons .. either a picture that would state the meaning of the button or simply show the name of the button. If you show a picture AND  have to describe the button, it means your users wouldn't understand the meaning of the picture, and furthermore, the button. Thus you failed User eXperience! (as a reference to your jsfiddle, @gec100)

Comment: hmm. thx. good point. i did intend to explain icons with text. just thought of it design wise. but i'm total design shmuck so ... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you are almost there...  Look at this one, using your code.

http://jsfiddle.net/fg7Ya/

It will output the same image for each button.

If we go further, we get this:

http://jsfiddle.net/fg7Ya/2/

Which is this, in short:

```
.btn.client:before {
        background: url("http://www.klm.com/jobs/nl/images/icon_updateprofile_tcm701-313773.gif") no-repeat left center transparent;
}

.btn.poslovnica:before {
        background: url("http://www.dhl.nl/content/dam/General%20DHL%20pictures/Icons/Small%20teasers_50x50/dhl_open_account_icon_42x40.jpg") no-repeat left center transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you want to keep your gradient and have those icons within your button? If so, use `background-image` for your icons. This will keep the background gradient:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VkCB3/)

```
.client{    
    background-image: url("../img/client.png") no-repeat left center transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
.poslovnica{    
    background-image: url("../img/poslovnica.png") no-repeat left center transparent;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

Moreover, you schould remove the `<p>` Tag from the anchor.

Comment: thx. that did fix the gradient but did not show different icon. just the first one defined.

Answer (score 0):

you just need your `background-size` this will keep background color.
 check out this fiddle :

http://jsfiddle.net/C45ks/

```
.client{    
   background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg") 
no-repeat left center transparent;
**background-size: 20% 60%;**
}
.poslovnica{    
background: url("http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Approve_icon.svg")
no-repeat left center transparent;
**background-size: 20% 60%;**
}
```

Comment: thx. good solution. just a bit more complicated than one from Siyahs